# How to append an extra AND statement to a WHERE clause based on a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql query I am writing to select from multiple tables. I also am creating a temp table based on an Ids variable

```
 IF @IDs IS NOT NULL   
 BEGIN   
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable(id nvarchar(12))       
    INSERT #TempTable (id)    
    SELECT x.value    
    FROM string_split(@IDs, ',') x      
END
```

After this, I am selecting things based on multiple conditions.

```
WHERE m.l_var = @l_var
AND m.o_var = @o_var
AND tvar BETWEEN @Start AND @End
AND m.id in (SELECT id FROM #TempTable)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

How do I write the last AND statement to where I can check if @IDs is null like when I'm creating the table?

For reference, this is the logic I want, but I don't know how to write it correctly:

```
WHERE ....
AND ...
AND..
AND IF NOT NULL @IDs m.id in (SELECT id FROM #TempTable)
    OR ELSE DON'T APPEND
```

Comment: `and @IDs is null or m.id in (SELECT id FROM #TempTable)` ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh Sql server management studio

Comment: @TheImpaler I will try it.

Comment: @PatrickS SSMS is purely a client UI, its not the database engine, you are using SQL Server and  want `select @@version` for the version.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you, this seems to be correct!

Comment: @DaleK Sorry, I didn't know what he was talking about when he said DBMS, I am using SQL Server 2017, but it seems as though Impalers comment is correct.

Comment: @PatrickS I forgot to add the parenthesis, as in `and (@IDs is null or m.id in (SELECT id FROM #TempTable))`.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yeah I caught that when I put it in. Thank you though.

Comment: You should use a Table Valued Parameter instead of splitting csv strings

Answer (score 1):

The logic looks like:

```
WHERE .... AND
      . . .AND ..
      (@IDs IS NULL OR m.id in (SELECT t.id FROM #TempTable t))
```

I'm not sure why you are using a temporary table.  I might suggest:

```
WHERE .... AND
      . . .AND ..
      (@IDs IS NULL OR m.id in (SELECT s.value FROM string_split(@IDs, ',') s)
```